# Run ASE MD in parallel

Tags: high-performance-computing, atomic-simulation-environment

I would like to run my MD simulation in parallel on a cluster (16 CPUs per node).

From the [ASE doc](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/parallel.html) we can see that:

> ASE will automatically run in parallel, if it can import an MPI communicator from any of the supported libraries. ASE will attempt to import communicators from these external libraries: GPAW, Asap, Scientific MPI and MPI4PY.

I submit a slurm script with these options:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
...

srun python ase_script.py
...
```

It looks like the fastest is always the single cpu calculation and increasing the ntasks per core (1 to 16), makes the calculation go slower.

The only difference I see is that the log output contains multiple lines (times ntasks-per-node) for a given step, but with different results. E.g., for a Velocity Verlet calculation and 8 cpus per nodes, I get:

```
Time[ps]      Etot[eV]     Epot[eV]     Ekin[eV]    T[K]
...
0.0440        -8297.460    -8299.281        1.821    79.6
0.0440        -8297.476    -8299.305        1.829    80.0
0.0440        -8297.477    -8299.304        1.827    79.8
0.0440        -8297.741    -8299.557        1.816    79.4
0.0440        -8297.744    -8299.563        1.819    79.5
0.0440        -8297.744    -8299.570        1.826    79.8
0.0440        -8297.746    -8299.584        1.838    80.3
0.0440        -8297.749    -8299.612        1.863    81.4
...
```

I have tried to decorate my dynamics function with `@parallel_function` (before the definition and before `run()` method) but I get an error.

I have installed all the required libraries in my conda environment:

```
$ conda list > conda_list

$ cat conda_list | grep -e asap -e gpaw -e mpi
asap3                     3.12.12         py310hb818612_2            conda-forge
gpaw                      23.9.1          py310_mpi_openmpi_omp_0    conda-forge
gpaw-data                 0.9.20000            hd8ed1ab_2            conda-forge
mpi                       1.0                     openmpi            conda-forge
mpi4py                    3.1.4           py310h6075a6b_0            conda-forge
openmpi                   4.1.5              h414af15_101            conda-forge
```

Is there something else I can try?

Small side question, how can I print the volume of the cell in ASE output above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually MD routines is not the bottleneck of the calculation. Usually it is better to focus on parallelisation of the calculator. There is a `communicator` parameter in constructors of `MolecularDynamics` instances: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/md.html. And by default it should be the `world` one, but I would rather specify it explicitly. In any way, this communicator can't be used to distribute energy and calculation. You should explicitly do it. Probably it is better to run the python script in a single process and then call the calculator process with `mpiexec` or `srun`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is clear.
The calculator used is XTB, which does not seem to have any notion of parallelism: https://xtb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ase-calculator.html